# How to find date from string with PHP

Tags: php, date

I have outside HTML file, that I read to PHP variable. In this HTML file there are different dates(and times). What would be the easiest way to read them to variable.
Date-time is always in the following format:
`<td align="left" valign="middle" class="contentValueFont">01-Mar-14 19:24:45 GMT</td>`
Ofcourse date and time change.
In other place I used to search with class name and read all the following to variable until `</td>` comes, but this time same class name is used in different places, not associated with my date/time.
I am not good at regular expressions.

Thanks for help.
T.

Comment: Not good at regular expressions? Well, you should use them, so better make that effort. Nothing is easy at programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
preg_match('/\d\d-[A-Z]{3}-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [A-Z]{3}/i', $html, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Based on your comment, this will get all of the dates of that format:

```
preg_match_all('/\d\d-[A-Z]{3}-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [A-Z]{3}/i', $html, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Downvote because it doesn't work or what?

Comment: @ykstom: Edited.  Retrieves all dates.

Comment: This expression results: >01-Mar-14 19:24:45 GMT<. How to get without ><

Comment: @ykstom: Edited, just remove the `>` and `<`.  Use the second one for ALL dates.

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression is not the right tool for the job. Use an [HTML parser](http://php.net/domdocument) to extract the date and [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class to do the processing:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<td align="left" valign="middle" class="contentValueFont">01-Mar-14 19:24:45 GMT</td>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$date = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$dateObj = new DateTime($date);
echo $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2014-03-01 19:24:45
```

Comment: Isn't a RegEx a better option (faster and memory efficient). Especially since dates follow a common format.

Comment: @ItayGrudev: Sure, the dates *can* be extracted using a regex, but it's just better to use an HTML parser instead, so you can be sure that it works *every* time.

Comment: @ItayGrudev: See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1438393).

Comment: They stated that the classname is not unique, so how do you propose finding the correct `td` for the date?

Comment: @AmalMurali I totally agree. Just the statement "you can be sure that it works every time" is enough.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use regular expressions (very little), but php provides [this](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function for exactly your needs.

Comment: The question is about finding the date string within a HTML document string, not about converting that string into a timestamp.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$unix = strtotime('01-Mar-14 19:24:45 GMT'); //get unix timestamp
echo date('d-M-y H:i:s', $unix); // output in any format
//output - 01-Mar-14 19:24:45
```

Reference to all character that can be used in date() for formatting: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The question is about finding the date string within a HTML document string, not about converting that string into a timestamp.

Comment: Oh okay, I assumed it was being POST'ed in a form.